# vim regex: negative backreferences?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to match XML entries where the link doesn't correspond to the link text, like this:

```
<link linkend="G431">X595</link>
```

but NOT links where the link text is correct, like this:

```
<link linkend="G431">G431</link>
```

How can I write a vim regex to match the first of those? I've tried things like:

```
linkend="\([A-Z]\d\+\)">[^\1]
```

and

```
linkend="\([A-Z]\d\+\)">^\(\1\)\@!
```

but I can't quite seem to get anything to work. Basically I'm trying to say "find a link where the link text does NOT equal the link location."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second variant you have `…\)">^\(\1\)\@!…`. You don’t need caret here: it means itself (caret) in this position (usually it means “start of line”, but not there: see `:h /^`). Neither you need parenthesis (they do not harm, but they are not needed):

```
linkend="\([A-Z]\d\+\)">\1\@!
```

. Negation is expressed via `!` (positive look-ahead is `\@=`). In `[^\1]` variant you match any character, but backslash, ASCII one and line break: collections do not support back references and even if they did support it it would be illogical for a collection to match more then one character (so if they did it would pull a set of characters present in a matched text).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is pretty close to being correct.

I just used negative lookahead as seen here:

```
linkend="\([A-Z]\d\+\)">\(\1\)\@!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/<link linkend="\(.*\)">\(\1\)<\/link>
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want to match. I want to match *not* \1.